# Create CSV and save on local/server automatically

Tags: php, csv, download

I need to create a CSV file in PHP and that created file should be saved on local/server rather than asking to save.

Comment: just write the out put to a file instead of outputting to browser

Comment: Could you clarify or provide more details please? I am interpreting your question as: "I have a server running PHP. I need generate a CSV file in PHP and save on the local filesystem." -- is that the correct interpretation? I guess I don't understand when you would be "asked to save."

Comment: Search is your friend - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398750/create-csv-file-using-php-and-save-it-into-directory

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the PHP versions later than 5.1.0 you can use the built-in CSV functions.

```
<?php

$data_array = array (
            array ('col1','col2'),
            array ('2','2'),
            array ('3','6'),
            array ('4','2'),
            array ('6','5')
        );

$fp = fopen('csvfile.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

---

This code will do the trick

```
$data_array = array (
            array ('1','2'),
            array ('2','2'),
            array ('3','6'),
            array ('4','2'),
            array ('6','5')
            );

$csv = "col1,col2 \n";//Column headers
foreach ($data_array as $record){
    $csv.= $record[0].','.$record[1]."\n"; //Append data to csv
    }

$csv_handler = fopen ('csvfile.csv','w');
fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
fclose ($csv_handler);

echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';
```

but be sure about permission of csvfile so your script can create or write on it

Comment: @samyMassoud Does the `csvfile.csv` already have to exist on the server or are you creating this on the fly?

Comment: `fopen` will create it on the fly , if it has permission over folder of this file