# How can i directly send data to excel sheet (not in database) using laravel CRUD application?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm developing a site where user asked me to create a application using laravel crud but he asked me to send data directly to excel sheet without database.

Comment: You can use any widget that allows you to add, edit and delete in excel.

Comment: I don't if that possible right now, but in my point of view, you should use a database, and create a job that will export and import data from the database to an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open CSVs in Excel so if you simply create a CSV file (on the server?) or wherever you want it - the client can open that in excel and treat it as a normal spreadsheet. 
[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398750/create-csv-file-using-php-and-save-it-into-directory) about how to create and store the file.